# Node.js close the writestream at the end of the readstream

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, async-await, stream, es6-promise

I am reading through a csv file stored on AWS S3. Those csv records are evaluated by a function called filterLogic(). Those record which fail the test need to be written into an error report csv file on AWS S3 as well. For the csv parsing I am using fast-csv.

However, for the last record I get a `"Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end"`

Where and how do I need to call `csvwritestream.end()` correctly?

```html
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const utils = require('./utils');
const csv = require('fast-csv');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log("Incoming Event: ", JSON.stringify(event));
    const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    const filename = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    const message = `File is uploaded in - ${bucket} -> ${filename}`;
    console.log(message);

    const splittedFilename = filename.split('.');
    const reportFilename = splittedFilename[0] + "Report." + splittedFilename[1];
    const reportBucket = 'external.transactions.reports';

    const csvwritestream = csv.format({ headers: true });
    csvwritestream
        .pipe(utils.uploadFromStream(s3, reportBucket, reportFilename))
        .on('end', function () {
            console.log("Report written to S3 " + reportFilename);
        });

    var request = s3.getObject({ Bucket: bucket, Key: filename });
    var stream = request.createReadStream({ objectMode: true })
        .pipe(csv.parse({ headers: true }))
        .on('data', async function (data) {
            stream.pause();
            console.log("JSON: " + JSON.stringify(data));
            var response = await utils.filterLogic(data);
            if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
                await csvwritestream.write(data);
                console.log("Data: " + JSON.stringify(data) + " written."); 
            }
            stream.resume();
        })
        .on('end', function(){
            csvwritestream.end();   
        });
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        stream.on('close', async function () {
            csvwritestream.end();
            resolve();
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your error is and isn't simple. The main issue there is the fact that the listener `data` is not awaited for in [node.js event emitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_eventname_listener) - so as you may expect that the data processing is started in order, the time when that is finished isn't. Now taking that into account see that the `end` event is fired immediately after the last `data` event and therefore the write of some of the last processed items is done after the write stream is closed... and yes, I know you did pause, but in an `async function` you did so after the synchronous stuff was handled by node and `end` is one of .

What you could do is implement a Transform stream, but that, given your use case may be much more complicated than just using another module - like my [`scramjet`](https://scramjet.org/) that will allow you to run asynchronous code in data filters.

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const utils = require('./utils');
const {StringStream} = require('scramjet');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log("Incoming Event: ", JSON.stringify(event));
    const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    const filename = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    const message = `File is uploaded in - ${bucket} -> ${filename}`;
    console.log(message);

    const splittedFilename = filename.split('.');
    const reportFilename = splittedFilename[0] + "Report." + splittedFilename[1];
    const reportBucket = 'external.transactions.reports';

    var request = s3.getObject({ Bucket: bucket, Key: filename });
    var stream = StringStream
        // create a StringStream from a scramjet stream
        .from(
            request.createReadStream()
        )
        // then just parse the data
        .CSVParse({headers: true})
        // then filter using asynchronous function as if it was an array
        .filter(async data => {
            var response = await utils.filterLogic(data);
            return response.statusCode === 200;
        })
        // then stringify
        .CSVStringify({headers: true})
        // then upload
        .pipe(
            utils.uploadFromStream(s3, reportBucket, reportFilename)
        );

    return new Promise(
        (res, rej) => stream
            .on("finish", res)
            .on("error", rej)
    );
};
```

Scramjet will take care of creating a stream pipeline from the above methods, so you don't need to pause/resume  - that's all taken care of.

You may want to read:

- [DataStream..filter](https://scramjet.org/docs/data-stream/#module_scramjet.DataStream+filter)
- [Configs for CSVParse/CSVStringify from Papa Parse](https://www.papaparse.com/docs#config)

Oh, and scramjet adds 3 deps only, so your node modules won't be a case of that relativistic joke. ;)